# XPATH - How to extract this?

Tags: php, xpath

**OBJECTIVE:** Get values of anchor link (some_path) and anchor value (User Name) **using only and only** anchor ID (msg123456) as starting point.

**HTML:**

```
<!-- a lot of HTML code before this -->
<a id="msg123456"></a><a id="new"></a>
<div class="windowbg">
    <span class="topslice"><span></span></span>
    <div class="post_wrapper">
        <div class="poster">
            <h4><a href="some_path" title="some_user">User Name</a></h4>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<!-- a lot of HTML code after this -->
```

**PROBLEM:** I know how to use XPATH for simple tasks, but in this situation Im not sure from where to start.

Comment: Please post valid XML if asking for XQuery-Code. The comments are no valid XML tags, why not using XML comments for providing them? Post your idea and what you tried before asking next time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fetch the anchor tag which you can search for, this is still easy. The more difficult part is finding the next div, which you can do using `following-sibling::div[1]` which fetches the first `<div/>` following on the same level after the current context. The stuff after that is easy again.

For the path:

```
//a[@id="msg123456"]/following-sibling::div[1]//a/@href/data()
```

For the user name:

```
//a[@id="msg123456"]/following-sibling::div[1]//a/data()
```

Comment: Im receiving: Warning: DOMXPath::query() [domxpath.query]: Invalid expression in...

Comment: With help of @hakre, no more errors. I have to remove /data() as this is not Xpath 1.0

Comment: And next time also post your XPath engine. :)